# delete number rightaway from input not working jquery

Tags: jquery

Im using the number `1` from my keyboard to write the letter `ä` in my input...
I works but I want to remove immediately the  number.

```js
  $("#search").keypress(function(e){
                if (e.which == 49) 
                {
                    $(this).val($(this).val()+"ä"); 
                };
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id="search" />
<br>
<br>
What I want is the next (after pressing several times "1")
<br><br>
<input type=text id="example" value="äääääääääää" />
```

I have already added `.replace(1, "")` but not workeing properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the key is `49`, you want to prevent the default behavior of `1` being added to the input. This can be done with `e.preventDefault()`:

```js
$("#search").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 49) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val($(this).val() + "ä");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id="search" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` to solve the problem.

```
$("#search").keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 49) 
    {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).val($(this).val()+"ä"); 
    };
});
```